# Angular svg icon size

Tags: angularjs, svg, angular-material

I'm making an angular js application and I'm using the icons found https://materialdesignicons.com/
I'm having trouble creating large icons in my project. I'm currently assigning the icons like so.

```
app.config(function($mdIconProvider) {
$mdIconProvider
    .defaultIconSet('assets/icon/materialdesignicons.svg')
    .iconSet(['large'], 'assets/icon/materialdesignicons.svg');
```

});
I know the default size is 24px, but if I put in a number like 48, the image shrinks instead of gets larger.
What should I put in instead of large?

Comment: that parameter does not set the size of the icon but instead the viewbox size for the svg. see here : https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1785

Comment: any idea why default size is 24px ?

Answer (score 1):

1. If your icon svg element has a viewBox attribute, it won't be overwritten by the $mdIconProvider size attribute.
2. The size parameter defines the `viewBox` height and width. `viewBox` only affects the coordinate system of an SVG element. It should match the dimension of your icon; if they don't match, md-icon might show a zoomed in/out view of the icon.

   However, the actual size of a md-icon element will be defined by its height and width (defined with css); the SVG element will scale up and down inside the md-icon.

---

`viewBox` is a requirement for a svg element to scale. It sets which portion of its grid to show and how the element in the svg element should scale with it. it just doesn't decide the actual size of the icon which grow with md-iconelement size.

- *If `viewBox` is not set, the svg elements will not scale (that's the
  jQuery bug); one unite will be 1px regardless of the svg element
  size.*
- *If you set the size to something smaller than the svg grid (e.g. "0 0
  12 12" for a 24x24 grid), you will zoom onto the top left corner of
  the icon.*
- *If you set the size to something bigger than the grid (e.g. "0 0 48
  48" for a 24 x 24 grid), you will zoom out with the the icon placed
  in the top left corner of the svg element.*

You can find lot more details [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1785).

Comment: I thought by default the viewbox is set to 24 by default. I took out the dependency on jQuery.
I also manually set the icon size and height, but that still has an issue
Setting the width and height still don't fix the issue though.
Changing the css for md-icon doesn't solve the issue either

Comment: You are experiencing  the natural behavior of the argument. Please follow my text carefully: *viewBox is a requirement for a svg element to scale. It sets which portion of its grid to show and how the element in the svg element should scale with it. it just doesn't decide the actual size of the icon which grow with md-iconelement size.*

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out the problem. The icon was being used as a button, but I had the class md-icon-button for the button in addition to the icon. Removing the class from the button fixed the issue.